# community cloud salesforce creating new record does not display record details

Tags: community-cloud

I have created "Salesforce Object" based navigation for a custom object with multiple record types on experience cloud site. When I click "New" button I am able to see all the necessary fields and am able to create a new record as well. But, the moment I click "Save" Salesforce redirects me to the list page instead of showing Record details page.

Any help on this topic is appreciated.

Comment: If you are using the site for guest users, they don't have edit access to records. They can only Read and create records based on profile permissions and salesforce doesn't let you stay on the record after creation